# Java Apache BOBYQA optimization termination criteria

Tags: java, optimization, apache-commons-math

I am trying to solve a 2 dimensional optimization problem using [BOBYQA](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/optim/nonlinear/scalar/noderiv/BOBYQAOptimizer.html) Optimization Java library provided by Apache Math. If I understood correctly, the only termination/convergence criteria in BOBYQA Java library is the minimum trust region radius. As for the Python implementation of [BOBYQA](https://numericalalgorithmsgroup.github.io/pybobyqa/build/html/index.html), one can terminate the optimization based on the objective function value as well.

I can see that in Java, optimization still keeps on running even though the value of the objective function is acceptable. I want to terminate the optimization when the value of objective function is lower than the acceptable value. Is there a way in Java implementation of BOBYQA to terminate the optimization based on the objective function value?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).